# Use GEKKO solver in scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, gekko, scipy-optimize-minimize

I try to use the scipy.optimze.minimize solver (Nelder-Mead) to optimize my parameters of a GEKKO simulation.

Is this possible at all?

My idea was to hand over the GEKKO object to the solver, but this leads to a error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'GEKKO'
```

But without handing over the object, I couldn´t get the GEKKO solver starting.

Attached is an easy version of the code, doing nothing which makes sense, just for technical understanding, and maybe showing the error I did.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy.random import rand
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()             # create GEKKO model
x = m.Var    # define new variable
y = m.Var    # define new variable

# objective function
def objective(m,v):

    x, y = v
    m.Equations([x + 2 * y == 0, x ** 2 + y ** 2 == 1])  # equations
    m.solve(disp=False)  # solve
    print([x.value[0], y.value[0]])  # print solution

    return x

# define range for input
r_min, r_max = -5.0, 5.0
# define the starting point as a random sample from the domain
pt = r_min + rand(2) * (r_max - r_min)
# perform the search
result = minimize(objective, m, pt, method='nelder-mead')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that mixes `Gekko` and `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy.random import rand
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # create GEKKO model
x = m.Var() # define new variable
y = m.Var() # define new variable
m.Equations([x + 2 * y == 0, x ** 2 + y ** 2 == 1])  # equations

# objective function
def objective(v):
    x.value = v[0]
    y.value = v[1]
    m.solve(disp=False)  # solve
    print([x.value[0], y.value[0]])  # print solution
    return x.value[0]

# define range for input
r_min, r_max = -5.0, 5.0
# define the starting point as a random sample from the domain
pt = r_min + rand(2) * (r_max - r_min)
# perform the search
result = minimize(objective, pt, method='nelder-mead')
```

The values need to be transferred into Gekko with `x.value=v[0]` and `y.value=v[1]` and exported from Gekko with `return x.value[0]`. The objective of this problem is to find the root (among the 2) that gives the lowest value of `x`.

[image: two solutions]

Another way to do this with just Gekko is to minimize x:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy.random import rand
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # create GEKKO model
x = m.Var() # define new variable
y = m.Var() # define new variable
m.Equations([x + 2 * y == 0, \
             x ** 2 + y ** 2 == 1])
m.Minimize(x)
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

This also produces the correct solution `[-0.8944271912,0.4472135956]`.